# Set a correlation variable for receive task with camunda bpmn 2.0

Tags: bpmn, camunda-modeler

I am new to the camunda workflow modeller. I am trying to create a workflow with bpmn 2.0 as follows

[image]

In the receive task I also added the correlation message as follows

[image: Receive task settings]

But the workflow is expecting to businessKey or  CorrelationKey for receive tasks. Camunda documentation says its possible as per the link

https://docs.camunda.io/docs/1.1/guides/message-correlation/

But I don't any such options could be set in my camunda modeller as shown in my second diagram . Is there a problem with my camunda version I use I am not sure. Due to this I am not able to correlate my message in receive task.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Adding my camunda bpmn also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:modeler="http://camunda.org/schema/modeler/1.0" id="Definitions_1ol3ys3" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="4.12.0" modeler:executionPlatform="Camunda Platform" modeler:executionPlatformVersion="7.15.0">
  <bpmn:process id="Process_1gdubba" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_1gzqzne" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="bookPackage" />
    <bpmn:endEvent id="Event_1ymhad0">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_1j5ss28</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_105dr0i" sourceRef="bookPackage" targetRef="WaitForBookingOrder" />
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="bookPackage" name="Book Package" camunda:asyncBefore="true">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:connector>
          <camunda:inputOutput>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="headers">
              <camunda:map>
                <camunda:entry key="content-type">application/json</camunda:entry>
              </camunda:map>
            </camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="payload">${OrderDetails}</camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="method">POST</camunda:inputParameter>
            <camunda:inputParameter name="url">http://localhost:8080/order/bookOrder</camunda:inputParameter>
          </camunda:inputOutput>
          <camunda:connectorId>http-connector</camunda:connectorId>
        </camunda:connector>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_1gzqzne</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_105dr0i</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:serviceTask>
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Booking Details Entered" camunda:initiator="initiator-1">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:formData>
          <camunda:formField id="FormField_0vq0vhv" type="string" />
        </camunda:formData>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_1gzqzne</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_1j5ss28" sourceRef="WaitForBookingOrder" targetRef="Event_1ymhad0" />
    <bpmn:receiveTask id="WaitForBookingOrder" name="Wait for Order Booking" camunda:asyncBefore="true" messageRef="Message_0uzf0py">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_105dr0i</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_1j5ss28</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:receiveTask>
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmn:message id="Message_077dwge" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_1j9gxjh" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0k2uuhr" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_1k0sfyp" name="Message_126eokf" />
  <bpmn:signal id="Signal_04rb9k9" name="Signal_1kupnq8" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0kmdk8v" name="Message_1m6is76" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0bg1bci" name="Message_273179n" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_16e0u8x" name="Message_2dj35ou" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_12k4481" name="Message_3fq29kb" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_00ax63g" name="Message_0odalie" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0waz31j" name="Message_005vg07" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_06yphqu" name="Message_35sf91n" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0m445do" name="Message_2vut7h6" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_04gasop" name="Message_2n54vi8" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_088ugzc" name="Message_1b531ct" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_1rvnt8b" name="Message_3d4pilp" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0xi2an8" name="Message_2bdedqe" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_1gvhqy2" name="Message_3aujnko" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_1q13r23" name="Message_09b9rf6" />
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0uzf0py" name="WaitForBookingOrder">
     <bpmn:extensionElements>
            <camunda:properties>
               <camunda:property name="correlationKey" value="orderId" />
             </camunda:properties>
     </bpmn:extensionElements><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                              <bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:modeler="http://camunda.org/schema/modeler/1.0" id="Definitions_1ol3ys3" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="4.12.0" modeler:executionPlatform="Camunda Platform" modeler:executionPlatformVersion="7.15.0">
                                <bpmn:process id="Process_1gdubba" isExecutable="true">
                                  <bpmn:extensionElements>
                                    <camunda:properties>
                                      <camunda:property name="correlationKey" value="orderId" />
                                    </camunda:properties>
                                  </bpmn:extensionElements>
                                  <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_1gzqzne" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="bookPackage" />
                                  <bpmn:endEvent id="Event_1ymhad0">
                                    <bpmn:incoming>Flow_1j5ss28</bpmn:incoming>
                                  </bpmn:endEvent>
                                  <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_105dr0i" sourceRef="bookPackage" targetRef="WaitForBookingOrder" />
                                  <bpmn:serviceTask id="bookPackage" name="Book Package" camunda:asyncBefore="true">
                                    <bpmn:extensionElements>
                                      <camunda:connector>
                                        <camunda:inputOutput>
                                          <camunda:inputParameter name="headers">
                                            <camunda:map>
                                              <camunda:entry key="content-type">application/json</camunda:entry>
                                            </camunda:map>
                                          </camunda:inputParameter>
                                          <camunda:inputParameter name="payload">${OrderDetails}</camunda:inputParameter>
                                          <camunda:inputParameter name="method">POST</camunda:inputParameter>
                                          <camunda:inputParameter name="url">http://localhost:8080/order/bookOrder</camunda:inputParameter>
                                        </camunda:inputOutput>
                                        <camunda:connectorId>http-connector</camunda:connectorId>
                                      </camunda:connector>
                                    </bpmn:extensionElements>
                                    <bpmn:incoming>Flow_1gzqzne</bpmn:incoming>
                                    <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_105dr0i</bpmn:outgoing>
                                  </bpmn:serviceTask>
                                  <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Booking Details Entered" camunda:initiator="initiator-1">
                                    <bpmn:extensionElements>
                                      <camunda:formData>
                                        <camunda:formField id="FormField_0vq0vhv" type="string" />
                                      </camunda:formData>
                                    </bpmn:extensionElements>
                                    <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_1gzqzne</bpmn:outgoing>
                                  </bpmn:startEvent>
                                  <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_1j5ss28" sourceRef="WaitForBookingOrder" targetRef="Event_1ymhad0" />
                                  <bpmn:receiveTask id="WaitForBookingOrder" name="Wait for Order Booking" camunda:asyncBefore="true" messageRef="Message_0uzf0py">
                                    <bpmn:incoming>Flow_105dr0i</bpmn:incoming>
                                    <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_1j5ss28</bpmn:outgoing>
                                  </bpmn:receiveTask>
                                </bpmn:process>
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_077dwge" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_1j9gxjh" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_0k2uuhr" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_1k0sfyp" name="Message_126eokf" />
                                <bpmn:signal id="Signal_04rb9k9" name="Signal_1kupnq8" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_0kmdk8v" name="Message_1m6is76" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_0bg1bci" name="Message_273179n" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_16e0u8x" name="Message_2dj35ou" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_12k4481" name="Message_3fq29kb" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_00ax63g" name="Message_0odalie" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_0waz31j" name="Message_005vg07" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_06yphqu" name="Message_35sf91n" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_0m445do" name="Message_2vut7h6" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_04gasop" name="Message_2n54vi8" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_088ugzc" name="Message_1b531ct" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_1rvnt8b" name="Message_3d4pilp" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_0xi2an8" name="Message_2bdedqe" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_1gvhqy2" name="Message_3aujnko" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_1q13r23" name="Message_09b9rf6" />
                                <bpmn:message id="Message_0uzf0py" name="WaitForBookingOrder">
                                   <bpmn:extensionElements>
                                          <camunda:properties>
                                             <camunda:property name="correlationKey" value="orderId" />
                                           </camunda:properties>
                                   </bpmn:extensionElements>
                                </bpmn:message>
                                <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
                                  <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="Process_1gdubba">
                                    <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_1j5ss28_di" bpmnElement="Flow_1j5ss28">
                                      <di:waypoint x="720" y="127" />
                                      <di:waypoint x="792" y="127" />
                                    </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
                                    <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_105dr0i_di" bpmnElement="Flow_105dr0i">
                                      <di:waypoint x="470" y="127" />
                                      <di:waypoint x="620" y="127" />
                                    </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
                                    <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_1gzqzne_di" bpmnElement="Flow_1gzqzne">
                                      <di:waypoint x="208" y="127" />
                                      <di:waypoint x="370" y="127" />
                                    </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
                                    <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1ymhad0_di" bpmnElement="Event_1ymhad0">
                                      <dc:Bounds x="792" y="109" width="36" height="36" />
                                    </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
                                    <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_1sgn7mg_di" bpmnElement="bookPackage">
                                      <dc:Bounds x="370" y="87" width="100" height="80" />
                                    </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
                                    <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1ktohbs_di" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
                                      <dc:Bounds x="172" y="109" width="36" height="36" />
                                      <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                                        <dc:Bounds x="152" y="152" width="77" height="27" />
                                      </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
                                    </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
                                    <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_0abkrtc_di" bpmnElement="WaitForBookingOrder">
                                      <dc:Bounds x="620" y="87" width="100" height="80" />
                                    </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
                                  </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
                                </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
                              </bpmn:definitions>

  </bpmn:message>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="Process_1gdubba">
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_1j5ss28_di" bpmnElement="Flow_1j5ss28">
        <di:waypoint x="720" y="127" />
        <di:waypoint x="792" y="127" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_105dr0i_di" bpmnElement="Flow_105dr0i">
        <di:waypoint x="470" y="127" />
        <di:waypoint x="620" y="127" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_1gzqzne_di" bpmnElement="Flow_1gzqzne">
        <di:waypoint x="208" y="127" />
        <di:waypoint x="370" y="127" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1ymhad0_di" bpmnElement="Event_1ymhad0">
        <dc:Bounds x="792" y="109" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_1sgn7mg_di" bpmnElement="bookPackage">
        <dc:Bounds x="370" y="87" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1ktohbs_di" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="172" y="109" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="152" y="152" width="77" height="27" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_0abkrtc_di" bpmnElement="WaitForBookingOrder">
        <dc:Bounds x="620" y="87" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already have the answer or not, but the documentation that you refers is camunda 8.0, while yours is camunda 7.

I'm not sure about camunda 8, but in camunda 7, you can correlate with business key or variables.

https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.14/org/camunda/bpm/engine/runtime/MessageCorrelationBuilder.html